# Ruby on Rails - Devise model validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am working on a Ruby on Rails application, and I am using Devise gem for authentication. I have noted that I am able to sign up as a new user, but **all** the data of a user is not getting stored into Devise User model.

I have explained the scenario below.

- I have a User model. Below is the schema of the User model.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_08_07_053734) do
  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "company_departments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "department_code"
    t.string "department_name"
    t.string "department_haed"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.string "user_name"
    t.integer "user_identification_number"
    t.date "user_employment_start_date"
    t.date "user_DOB"
    t.string "user_present__job_title"
    t.string "user_department"
    t.string "user_employment_category"
    t.string "user_office_working_preference"
    t.string "user_social_status"
    t.string "user_present_office_location"
    t.string "user_present_working_shift"
    t.bigint "user_basic_pay"
    t.bigint "user_gross_salary"
    t.integer "user_appraisal_rating"
    t.date "user_last_salary_revision_date"
    t.text "user_appraisal_comments"
    t.bigint "user_contact"
    t.string "user_personalemail"
    t.text "user_permanent_address"
    t.string "user_manager"
    t.string "user_sup1"
    t.string "user_sup2"
    t.string "user_sup3"
    t.string "user_sup4"
    t.text "user_permanent_illness"
    t.string "user_phstatus"
    t.string "user_companyname"
    t.string "user_skill_category"
    t.boolean "user_account_status"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer "failed_attempts", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "company_department_id"
    t.index ["company_department_id"], name: "index_users_on_company_department_id"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  add_foreign_key "users", "company_departments"
end
```

- The User model contains of multiple columns (I have added extra columns to the User table in addition to Devise model traditional columns (email, password and password_confirmation)
- I have also created few tables (e.g. - CompanyDepartment table) in the database. The Department table is the parent table of the user table. Below are the details.

CompanyDepartment Model:

```
class CompanyDepartment < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :users
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable


  belongs_to :company_department, optional: true
end
```

**What am I trying to do? **

I want the records in the Company Department table to be available as a list of dropdown option for Devise signup form Department field.

**Observation: **

I have observed that Signup form is working but the Company Department data is not getting saved in the User table.

However, when I shift to Rails console and try to make changes from the backend using the below query, the department data gets successfully saved into the User table as below.

```
User.create!(user_name: "abc", password: 123456, password_confirmation: 123456, company_department_id: 3
```

**Thought Process**

I am thinking this is something related to Validations. Therefore, I had made sure that I have whitelisted all the User model attributes as below:

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    include DeviseWhitelist
end
```

**Devise Whitelist concern**

```
module DeviseWhitelist 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do 
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  end 

  def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:user_name, :user_identification_number, :user_employment_start_date, :user_DOB, :user_present__job_title, :user_department, :user_employment_category, :user_office_working_preference, :user_social_status, :user_present_office_location, :user_present_working_shift, :user_basic_pay, :user_gross_pay, :user_appraisal_rating, :user_last_salary_revision_date, :user_appraisal_comments, :user_contact, :user_personalemail, :user_permanent_address, :user_manager, :user_sup1, :user_sup2, :user_sup3, :user_sup4, :user_permanent_illness, :user_phstatus, :user_companyname, :user_skill_category, :user_account_status, **:company_department_id**])

    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:user_name, :user_identification_number, :user_employment_start_date, :user_DOB, :user_present__job_title, :user_department, :user_employment_category, :user_office_working_preference, :user_social_status, :user_present_office_location, :user_present_working_shift, :user_basic_pay, :user_gross_pay, :user_appraisal_rating, :user_last_salary_revision_date, :user_appraisal_comments, :user_contact, :user_personalemail, :user_permanent_address, :user_manager, :user_sup1, :user_sup2, :user_sup3, :user_sup4, :user_permanent_illness, :user_phstatus, :user_companyname, :user_skill_category, :user_account_status, **:company_department_id**])
  end 

end
```

Below is the form I am using for Signup. Its default Devise new registration form with an extra select field for Departments.

**Devise New User/Sign_Up form**

```
<h2>Sign up</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
    <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
    <% end %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_department %><br />
   <%= f.collection_select(:user_department, CompanyDepartment.all, :id, :department_name) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I am unable to understand why the department data is not getting saved and wanted to request help regarding this. Thank you.

Below, we can see that when POST request is initiated, the params are captured correctly but Department details are not saved.

[image: Message in the server]

Comment: I'm guessing you need `f.collection_select`, and not just `collection_select`, because it will not be a part of your resource otherwise.

Comment: @crodev Hi, Thank you for your response. I made the changes now I using Collection select as ```<%= f.collection_select(:user_department, CompanyDepartment.all, :id, :department_name) %>```. I am still seeing the same behavior. Added a supporting screenshot of the POST request processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to update `company_department_id`, so:

```
f.collection_select(:company_department_id ...
```

You've circled two different attributes, you're using correct attribute in the console but another one in the form - `user_department`, actually, does get updated.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. I made the changes and it worked. I struggled for a long time regarding ```select_tag```, ```collection_select``` tag. I couldn't find the exact syntax of it anywhere. And seeing the examples are trying to understand what could be what was very confusing. Therefore, I think I made mistake here. I was thinking there is some other issue probably validations. But seeing your response I now understand it was the form.  And also thank you because now I can actually understand how select tags work. Thanks

Comment: @TEJINDERSINGH you can look it up on rails api https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select